# Bool has not been declared

Tags: c++, boolean

I have been trying to do some programming in **c++** and i'm unable to understand what is the mistake here. 
 i'm using **code blocks** ide and when i run the program **the only error** i'm getting is

**error: 'boolean' has not been declared|**

||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===||

 Let me know, if you guys found any and put me in right direction. 

Ok. here is the actual code. But i'm not yet completed fully. i'm just halfway through.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isGoodCountry(char &countryName, int numCities, int numVillages, boolean hasNuclearPower, char &continentName, char &neighborCountries){

if(1==2){

    return false;
}
return true;

}
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    char countryName[25];
    int numCities, numVillages;
    bool hasNuclearPower;
    char continentName[25], neighborCountries[150];

    cout<<"Enter name of the Country: ";
    cin>>countryName;

    cout<<"Enter number of cities in the country: ";
    cin>>numCities;

    cout<<"Enter number of villages in the country: ";
    cin>>numVillages;

    cout<<" Does the country has Nuclear Power: ";
    cin>>hasNuclearPower;

    cout<<"Enter name of the continent: ";
    cin>>continentName;

    cout<<"Enter the neighbor countries names: ";
    cin>>neighborCountries;

    isGoodCountry(*countryName, numCities, numVillages, hasNuclearPower, *continentName, *neighborCountries);
    return 0;
}
```

**Thanks & regards**

Comment: You don't need #include <stdlib.h> and #include <stdbool.h>, instead if required you should include <cstdlib>

Comment: You don't need to add `#include<stdbool.h>` and `include<stdlib.h>` too.

Comment: what is this `if(condition 1){` ?

Comment: `condition 1` and `Some arguments` appear to be nonsense. What do you expect?

Comment: yah. even then the error is showing up.
@david I'm returning false if cond1 satisfies else true

Comment: @user322 - Post code that compiles?

Comment: As written your code never uses `boolean`. Could it be that your attempt to simplify has made the essential line of code disappear?

Comment: @ Floris Yah. in order to simplify i did like this. But, now i'hav written all

Comment: For the edited question, you are using `boolean` type, it should be `bool` in C++.

Comment: @user322 - Pls accept computerfreakers answer

Comment: Even i thought it would be wise, as he has relatively low points compared to you. Thanks agian.

Comment: @user322- that is why i suggested it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool isGoodCountry(char &countryName, int numCities, int numVillages, boolean hasNuclearPower, char &continentName, char &neighborCountries){
```

`boolean` isn't a type; you meant `bool`.

```
bool isGoodCountry(char &countryName, int numCities, int numVillages, bool hasNuclearPower, char &continentName, char &neighborCountries){
```

Comment: Your cut'n'paste is quicker than mine by 13 secs!

Comment: @Ed FGITW. ;) Still +1 for you, a right answer is a right answer regardless of when it's posted.

Comment: You got a +1 from me too

Comment: @ Ed Heal & @ computerfreaker
I'm feeling very stupidy after realising my mistake.. i'm lookin at the function instead of the arguments all the time. 
Anyhow, thanks for your time dudes..

Answer (score 4):

Should the line

```
bool isGoodCountry(char &countryName, int numCities, int numVillages, boolean hasNuclearPower, char &continentName, char &neighborCountries){
```

be

```
 bool isGoodCountry(char &countryName, int numCities, int numVillages, bool hasNuclearPower, char &continentName, char &neighborCountries){
```

Comment: Now, i'm confused whom to accept the answer among both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
bool isGoodCountry(char &countryName, int numCities, int numVillages, boolean hasNuclearPower, char &continentName, char &neighborCountries)
```

you should write

```
bool isGoodCountry(char &countryName, int numCities, int numVillages, bool hasNuclearPower, char &continentName, char &neighborCountries)
```

boolean is not a data type. The data type is bool.

in your `if` statement you write

```
if(1==2)
```

this can't be possible, so the function will always return true, so why you have to use `if` ?